# Multiple SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

here is my formula I am currently working on: =SUMIFS(Leuf!G2:G1705, Leuf!D2:D1705, "January", Leuf!J2:J1705)

here is the sample data:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWEXd.png

I am trying to calculate the total gallons based on the month in column F and also the column D as there are two different options "Clear Led" and "Dyed." I need to separate the cost but my current formula will not work.

Comment: The *first* argument of SUMIFS should be the column to be summed. You put it last. Plus you're missing some criteria.

Comment: thanks, I got it figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This -

=Sumifs("Sum Range", Criteria Range 1, Criteria, Criteria Range 2, Criteria)

In your case formula should be

=sumifs(j:j,G:G,"January",D:D,"Clear LED")